# Is there a way to extract the mean values from a boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, boxplot

How do I extract the mean values (displayed in points) from the boxplot to a new dataframe?

Using code:

```
ggplot (df, aes(x = Place, y= C2.dn, fill = Consonant)) + 
geom_boxplot() + stat_summary(fun= "mean", position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

I wish to extract the mean values (which is duration in milliseconds) for 'Consonant' (Singleton/Geminate) spoken at different 'Place'.

Data:

```
Filename Speaker Gender Consonant           Place Manner   Voicing Beforevowel C1_xsampa     C1.dn
1    AK_baga.TextGrid       1      F Singleton           Velar   Stop    Voiced       Short         b  9.659531
2   AK_bagga.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate           Velar   Stop    Voiced       Short         b 13.482264
3   AK_chape.TextGrid       1      F Singleton        Bilabial   Stop Voiceless       Short        tS 14.986702
4  AK_chappe.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate        Bilabial   Stop Voiceless       Short        tS 16.130656
5    AK_fati.TextGrid       1      F Singleton       Retroflex   Stop Voiceless       Short         f 11.597134
6   AK_fatti.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate       Retroflex   Stop Voiceless       Short         f 14.337659
7    AK_gada.TextGrid       1      F Singleton Dental/alveolar   Stop    Voiced       Short         g 11.403534
8   AK_gadda.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate Dental/alveolar   Stop    Voiced       Short         g 20.604107
9    AK_kala.TextGrid       1      F Singleton Dental/alveolar Liquid    Voiced       Short         k 11.324600
10  AK_kalla.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate Dental/alveolar Liquid    Voiced       Short         k 12.470790
11  AK_katha.TextGrid       1      F Singleton Dental/alveolar   Stop Voiceless       Short         k 13.018392
12   AK_kute.TextGrid       1      F Singleton Dental/alveolar   Stop Voiceless       Short         k 11.877616
13  AK_kutte.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate Dental/alveolar   Stop Voiceless       Short         k 12.218021
14  AK_manni.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate Dental/alveolar  Nasal    Voiced       Short         m 11.558052
15   AK_rami.TextGrid       1      F Singleton        Bilabial  Nasal    Voiced       Short         r  3.742659
16  AK_rammi.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate        Bilabial  Nasal    Voiced       Short         r  5.848195
17   AK_sada.TextGrid       1      F Singleton Dental/alveolar   Stop    Voiced       Short         s 17.866128
18   AK_saka.TextGrid       1      F Singleton           Velar   Stop Voiceless       Short         s 11.232963
19  AK_sakka.TextGrid       1      F  Geminate           Velar   Stop Voiceless       Short         s 14.246537
20   AK_sune.TextGrid       1      F Singleton Dental/alveolar  Nasal    Voiced       Short         s 10.934916
C2_xsampa     C2.dn V1_xsampa    V1.dn V2_xsampa    V2.dn total.dn
1         g  5.159067         @ 9.220461        A: 13.48245 37.52150
2         g: 15.033321         @ 5.249731        A: 15.39126 49.15657
3          p  8.004261         @ 8.190506        e: 12.43744 43.61891
4         p: 16.455435         @ 7.469901        e: 11.58376 51.63975
5         t`  8.422198         @ 5.798567        i: 12.34388 38.16178
6        t`: 15.216855         @ 5.883851        i: 10.27983 45.71820
7        d_d  7.947642         @ 7.051602        A: 16.54026 42.94304
8       d_d: 14.437914         @ 5.023191        A: 12.63318 52.69839
9          l  7.044436         @ 6.866096        A: 13.99970 39.23483
10        l: 16.590706         @ 4.382895        A: 10.93556 44.37995
11     t_d_h  8.711895         @ 7.447716        A: 11.38643 40.56444
12       t_d  7.360776         U 7.360776        e: 13.46687 40.06604
13      t_d: 19.717515         U 3.920708        e: 13.74527 49.60152
14        n: 14.590812         @ 5.072861        i: 10.99078 42.21250
15         m  8.648136         @ 9.060643        i: 13.42142 34.87286
16        m: 14.197970         @ 5.773448        i: 11.41324 37.23285
17       d_d  8.066670         @ 6.174324        A: 17.27497 49.38209
18         k  8.299910         @ 5.476070        A: 11.49180 36.50074
19        k: 20.130976         @ 3.974577        A: 11.77040 50.12249
20         n  6.515832         U 7.810508        e: 17.76466 43.02592
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do e.g. `df %>% group_by(Place, Consonant) %>% summarise(mean = mean(C2.dn))`?

Comment: @stefan, yes! this solved the purpose. I was thinking about using aggregate (). Could you please explain the code so that I understand it fully? Thanks.

Comment: `aggregate` should also do the job. My example is the tidy verse approach which first groups the data.frame by Place and Consonant and then uses summarise to compute the means per group.

Comment: Why would you adopt tidy verse approach? Any merits over simple aggregate?

Comment: Nop. Just a matter of taste or habit.

Comment: I see! Quick question: Is there a way to calculate the mean of all numeric columns (C1.dn, C2.dn, V1.dn, V2.dn) in the dataframe, 'df' collectively?

Comment: In the tidy verse you could do `df %>% group_by(Place, Consonant) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean))`

Comment: Now that is something aggregate () cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
aggregate(C2.dn ~ Place, df, mean)
```

Comment: Yes! That was my intention. In order to print the categorical variable, "Consonant', I would simply do 'aggregate(C2.dn ~ Place + Consonant, df, mean)'. 
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(C2.dn = mean(C2.dn, na.rm = TRUE)), Place]
```